# Trouble getting date value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parameters

I am modifying a webpage.  Webpage is using visual basic and my database is a SQL database.

The webpage gives me the total Sick, Comp, and Vacation time off.  Right now, I get the logon name of whoever's logged onto the computer, and I look up the EmployeeID in a tblEmployees so I can search tblTimeAvailable by the EmployeeID, and then add up the different times.

I want to also get the StartDate from tblEmployees so I can also search by anniversary date (after I calculate it from the Start Date). I'm getting an error "Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'Date' on the rvsd=command2.ExecuteNonQuery line.  Here's my code:

```
    Dim rve As Object
    Dim rvsd As Date
    Dim dt As Date = Today

    'Get network login name (name only)
    split = windowsLoginName.Split("\".ToCharArray)
    vname = split(1)

    'Get employeeid from table that matches login name 
    Dim Connection As String = "Data Source=WillSQL\ict2;Initial Catalog=timesql_testing;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(Connection)
        Dim sqlemp As String = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM tblEmployees where login = @loginname"
        Dim sqlstdt As String = "SELECT StartDate FROM tblEmployees where login = @loginname"
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(sqlemp, con)
        Dim command2 As New SqlCommand(sqlstdt, con)
        con.Open()
        command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@loginname", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = vname})
        command2.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@loginname", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = vname})
        rve = command.ExecuteScalar
        rvsd = command2.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using

    Dim theDateThisYear As Date

    theDateThisYear = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(rvsd), Day(rvsd))

    If theDateThisYear < Now() Then
        theDateThisYear = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, theDateThisYear)
    End If

    Dim NextAnniversary As Date = theDateThisYear
    MsgBox(NextAnniversary)

        'Get Sick Time - DOES NOT INCLUDE CHECKING TO MAKE SURE LESS THAN ANNIV DATE YET
    Using con As New SqlConnection(Connection)
        Dim sqls1 As String = "Select SUM(NoofHours) as Total from tblTimeAvailable where workcode = 1 and EmployeeID = @emp"
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(sqls1, con)
        con.Open()
        command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@emp", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = rve})
        rvsa = command.ExecuteScalar
    End Using
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: Use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) - it will give a useful suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the column `[StartDate]` in the database has a type of DateTime then all you need to do is

```
rvsd = CDate(command2.ExecuteScalar)
```

Although you could have retrieved both values with one query:

```
SELECT [EmployeeID], [StartDate] FROM [tblEmployees] where [login] = @loginname"
```

and so

```
Dim rve As String
Dim rvsd As Date

Dim connStr As String = "Data Source=WillSQL\ict2;Initial Catalog=timesql_testing;Integrated Security=SSPI"
Dim sql = "SELECT [EmployeeID], [StartDate] FROM [tblEmployees] where [login] = @loginname"

Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@loginname", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = vname})
        conn.Open()
        Dim rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            rdr.Read()
            rve = rdr.GetString(0)
            rvsd = rdr.GetDateTime(1)
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Yeah!  Thanks a bunch!